# Count number of values within cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of values within a cell, in Excel. So far I have found plenty of ways to count the number of characters, regardless of whether they're a space, number, or letter. However, I would like to count the number of values in a list or a cell, like so:

Let's say in cell A1 I have the following sequence of values:

```
38 39 101 102 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125
```

I would like for the cell to return `16`, indicating that there are sixteen values in the cell.

Is there an easy way to do this with Excel?

Comment: If you found plenty of ways to count characters such as space, then use the one that counts spaces and subtract one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a known delimiter (what breaks up the values) and you don't have to test your data for whether it's a value or non-value then...

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[Your delimiter here]",""))+1
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187667

Comment: Might want to add 1 on the end. (That gives you 15.) Still cool though ^_^

Comment: Whoopsie, great catch! :)

Comment: Works great, except for one problem - it returns cells with no values in them as having 1 character in them. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe nest the above formula inside a `IF(ISERROR(FIND(` function?