# Count number of values that are being added

Tags: excel

I have the following excel cell

> =5+10+25

I want to count how many values I am adding, so for the about the result should be `3`

I tried [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311846/3024116) but it would only give me back 1 because it is applying the formula on `30` instead of `=5+10+25`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

`=(LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"+","")))+1`

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1)-SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"+","")+1
```

Comment: This will give an error as you are trying to subtract a string with a numeric value

Comment: Sorry, I got the brackets wrong. I fact, more is wrong with the formula, which proves I did not test it :-( 
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"+",""))+1